# Can I set default focus button showMessageBox in electron?

Tags: electron, messagebox

In the application quit confirm dialog, I want a way to set the button focused by default to No (N).
Also, Yes (Y), No (N) want to arrange them in this order (I do not want to use a method to arrange No (N) to the left).

```
function confirm_dialog(strtitle, strmessage) {
　   const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
 　  let choice = dialog.showMessageBox(
        remote.getCurrentWindow(),
            {
                type: 'question',
                buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
                title: strtitle,
                message: strmessage,
            });

    return choice === 0;
};
```

[confirm dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shlGi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`showMessgeBox` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback) explain this:

> `defaultId` Integer (optional) - Index of the button in the buttons array which will be selected by default when the message box opens.